# htaccess - How to remove everything after preceeding trailing slash in URI

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have 2 url patterns :

http://www.mondomaine.com/m/99/some-title-etc/

http://www.mondomaine.com/w/287/some-title-etc/

I want to hide/delete everything after the slash following the ID number, how would I do that in .htaccess file so it looks like this:

http://www.mondomaine.com/m/99/

http://www.mondomaine.com/w/287/

Of course, numbers are ID numbers. There are many of them and they are all different, I just show examples of the 2 patterns.

Here is what I have in my .htaccess file that is relevant to the /m/ part (similar for the /w/ part):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} m.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^m(.*)$ articles.php?$1 [T=application/x-httpd-php,L]
```

(I saw plenty of solutions here but none for my exact situation).

Comment: please provide more details to question.

Comment: hiding is one thing, but actually directing traffic is another. will all `/parts` be intended to load the page `/index` for example?

Comment: Just "cosmetic" hiding/deleting - My cms ignores the information after the last slash - it does not affect the location of the file.

Comment: yes but I don't know (and htaccess won't know) where the location of the destination file is. What is it?

Comment: here is an example - if you type http://www.place7.com/m/1 you end up at the right place, the cms knows.

Comment: Then why not just change the code to not add the title in the first place?\

Comment: Yes, this would be a solution, although when I submit my google sitemap (I have a software for that), it is important that the full url appears in the list.

Comment: If you have all your strings going to the same "index" file of that folder, and you have multiple strings, this will be detrimental to your SEO as you're repeating your content, Google and Bing and others will not look nicely upon this for more than two instances....  and what does your Cannonical link state, the base page name or the "expected" page name?

Comment: Not sure I understand your point. With or without the part I want to delete, each url is unique.

Comment: https://moz.com/beginners-guide-to-seo

Comment: Thanks I will read

Comment: I would like to also recommend [some excellent reading on Mod_rewrite](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-in-depth-guide-to-mod_rewrite-for-apache--net-6708)

Comment: From comments on my answer it has become clear that there are numerous other factors to take into consideration that the OP has not stated on their question (at this stage).

Answer (score 0):

**Updated again:**

This does as you require for any folder structure.

```
 RewriteEngine On
 #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d -Due to comments no longer needed.
 #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f -Due to comments no longer needed.
 RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*/+)$  /$1 [NC,L,QSA]

 #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d -Due to comments no longer needed.
 #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f -Due to comments no longer needed.
 RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$  /$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Line one:
Turn on Rwrite.

Line two:
Check that file requested is not a directory.

Line four: Remove all content after the final slash if there is an ending slash in the URI, this is removed and then page is directed to the new link.

Then the checks break because only one rewrite Rule can be applied at a time, so the first rule is applied and the URI is reloaded. then the second will be reached:

Line five: Is it a directory? No.

Line six: Is it a file? No.

Line seven: Remove everything after the final `/`. finish and visit the new location.

- QSA = Query string append. `?this=aquerystring`
- L = Last, last rule applied before visiting the newly generated destination path.
- NC = Not case sensitive.

Comment: Thank you. Although none of your solutions seems to affect the url - Btw the number is an ID, so there are plenty of them.

Comment: Martin, sorry! My mistake, there is a trailing slash after the title!

http://www.mondomaine.com/w/287/some-title-etc/ <--

And your previous solutions worked with no slash at the end!

Comment: Done, sorry Martin!

Comment: http://www.mondomaine.com/w/287/ is a file not a folder.
Your last solution do not seems to work.

Comment: was that in your question? I think not. How was I to know your ID numbers are actual files? If you want to check if a reference is a file add `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` underneath the directory checker and this will only rewrite URLs which do not meet file or folder specifications. :)

Comment: I hope that helps, @user3371049 ? `:-)`

Comment: I try to understand :), so far I do not get the desired resullt. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you tell us what URL you are using, and what your intended result from that URL is. My code works on my testing so either you have other rules interfereing wih my rules or your URL is a different shape from your examples? Cheers @user3371049

Comment: Sorry Martin, I make you lose your time. I did not know, folder/file was a consideration. Here is an url (one with title, if you click on the FR below the top menu icon, you will see a page without title). So you may understand better. http://www.ServiceSvp.com/m/1

Comment: @user3371049 so you want to turn `http://www.servicesvp.com/m/1/Create-your-Website-easily/` into `http://www.servicesvp.com/m/1/`, is that correct?

Comment: Exact, 1 is an ID so, for all IDs, and taking in consideration that sometimes, there won't be any title like on the page m/2/ and I would like it to work on different Domain names. I think this covers everything,

Comment: @user3371049 so `/1/` is an id but is ***not*** a file or a folder? so `/1/` should go to something (example) like `/index?id=1` (but not shown to the user) ?

Comment: (you stated in comments above that the id number was a file)

Comment: Yes sorry, my understanding of how it woks is limited. I knew it was not a directory, so....

Comment: The URL you gave me (`http://www.servicesvp.com/m/1/Create-your-Website-easily/`) works correctly on my tests, giving result: `http://www.servicesvp.com/m/1`. If it doesn't work it means that you have other htaccess rules interfering

Comment: Oh ok, that could be the case, I have a redirection and other things... I will debug the file. Thanks a lot. I will let you know.

Comment: Vous devez savoir quelle question à poser avant que je ne peux vous dire une réponse.

Comment: bon courage avec ca

Comment: Merci pour votre patience Martin! I updated my question to show what I have in my .htaccess file, and it answers your question about the hidden part: articles.php?$1

Comment: You need to add the edits I made in my answer *before* the code you have added to your question. So it rewrites the URI *before* applying it to `article.php`. That should help. @user3371049

Comment: Martin, I could not succeed in making it work. After all your help, I understand the subject more, so I asked an other question, in a better way - here is the url : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39292518/