# htaccess - Removing last segment after unique ID number in url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

In case there is something after a string that looks like this "/UniqueID (numbers only)/", e.g.: "/455/", in my url, I want to delete it.

Here is what I have in my htaccess file right now:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} m.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^m(.*)$ articles.php?$1 [T=application/x-httpd-php,L]
```

(I guess it adds a hidden extention "articles.php".

So, if my url looks like this:

```
www.mondomaine.com/m/234/ - no change needed for the visible part
```

If it looks like this:

```
www.mondomaine.com/m/121/some-title/ - I want to delete "some-title/"
www.mondomaine.com/m/121/ - result expected for the visible part
```

So, I guess we have to find "/numberonly/" and delete everything after it, then make sure the "articles.php" part remains. But I do not know how to do it.

Comment: This question doesn't ask anything you didn't ask in your original question. It would be better to delete this and edit your original question or vice versa, to delete your original question and just use this one.

Answer (score 0):

> (I guess it adds a hidden extention "articles.php".

No.

The `RewriteRule` takes an address that starts with `m` (and then anything) and gives it to `articles.php page`.

So:

Input (what browser sees):

> `m.domain/m/cheese/goats`

Output (page server actually loads):

> `m.domains/articles.php?/cheese/goats`

And from my answer to your previous question, which does work:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule ^(m/[0-9]+)/(.*)/?$ [NC,L,QSA]
```

This will rewrite any url beginning with `m/(numbers)` to cut off anything after the numbers.

So to use this in your current `.htaccess`:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} m.* #optional. 
 RewriteRule ^(m/[0-9]+)/?(.*)$ /$1 [NC,L,QSA]

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} m.*
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^m(.*)$ articles.php?$1 [T=application/x-httpd-php,L]
```

---

So now:
input = `http://www.mondomaine.com/m/121/treesand-horses/`

result of FIRST PART ONLY: (visible in the browser as a redirect):
`http://www.mondomaine.com/m/121`

And SECOND PART (not seen by browser):

`http://www.mondomaine.com/articles.php?/121`

Comment: Martin it gives me a http 404 error. when there is a title, without a title it works fine. I think it is related to the fact in your last line you show : articles.php?/121, I think the slash should not be there (just guessing),

Comment: check three things: 1) does the url work typing in `/articles.php?121`, does `/articles.php?121/` work with the trailing slash in the article request. And does  `/articles.php?/121/`,  work? As your work appears to be a CRM why are you trying to subvert the CRM behaviour? [read this](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-ultimate-guide-to-htaccess-files--net-4757) and [read this too](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

Comment: your htaccess currently sends the data to the articles page, I havn't altered that is if its an issue, it's secondary to the question :-p

Comment: I tested your 3 requests (without  your solution) none of it worked.
http://www.stylesvp.com/m/1 (with title) - http://www.stylesvp.com/m/2 witout title.It gives me a blank page. I will explain why I want to change later.

Comment: Ok, I want to change because my customers that do not own their domain names find the url to long to advertise, and it is hard to make them understand that they can cut it after the ID. Actualy, I am doing B2B and it is a request from Web Desigh Agencies I know I could do it via php but for another reasion I cannot. I did not have time to read your links yet, I will.

Comment: btw my system works exactly like stackoverflow, instead of "questions", I have an "m".

Comment: THe `article.php` rewrite rule does not parse the `m`, so it only takes anything AFTER the `m`, so you should pehaps update your `article.php` rewrite rule.

Comment: Also your test in comments above still retained the `m` but as I said - the `m` is lost in translation. The data that results is: `article.php?/121/` . no m.